# Unclear about what is SWR subscription

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, subscription, swr

I'm going through each of SWR's features and have encountered one that am unfamiliarized with: [SWR-subscription](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/subscription#useswrsubscription). I don't understand what they mean by "subscribing to real-time data sources with SWR". I am trying to look for an explanation and a simple example to understand this feature better and how would I apply it in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

A client subscribing to events means maintaining a persistent connection (e.g WebSocket protocol, `useSWRSubscription` hook) to some backend and constantly listening for new events, instead of just sending a single request (e.g HTTP protocol, `useSWR` hook).

---

> subscribing to real-time data sources with SWR

refers to maintaining a persistent connection via SWR (specifically via `useSWRSubscription()`) instead of just executing a HTTP request once with `useSWR()`.

This is required if you have real-time applications like a chat where you constantly have to listen to other user's messages. Executing just one HTTP request via `useSWR` to get messages other's have sent you would not be sufficient.

Instead, you would use the `useSWRSubscription` hook to actively listen (subscribe) to either your personal WebSocket server, or something like Firebase with real-time events. Then, whenever a new message would be sent, you could handle it appropriately with your SWR client, just like fetching any other regular data, and at the same time benefits from all the pros of SWR.

---

### Example

Here's a code snipped from the SWR docs that subscribes to events of a firebase realtime database:

```
import useSWRSubscription from 'swr/subscription'
 
function Post({ id }) {
  const { data } = useSWRSubscription(['views', id], ([_, postId], { next }) => {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref('views/' + postId)
    ref.on('value', 
      snapshot => next(null, snapshot.data()),
      err => next(err)
    )
    return () => ref.off()
  })
 
  return <span>Your post has {data} views!</span>
}
```

In this example, `data` will always be the **live** view count of some post, because you subscribe to all real-time changes of the view count via `useSWRSubscription`.

If you used `useSWR` instead, you would need to refresh the page to see the most up to date view count instead, or set a long-polling interval to refetch the view count periodically via the `refreshInterval` setting - but it would not be in **real time** anymore.